# AutoCADでブロック名称を変更したい

Tags: vba, autocad

お世話になっております。
AutoCAD2008 VBAについての質問です。
現存するブロックの名称を変更したいのですが、方法がわかりません。
現状、下記のようにプログラムを作成しています。

```
Dim objEntity As AcadEntity
For Each objEntity In ThisDrawing.ModelSpace

  '取り出された図形のAutoCADクラス名により対象か否かを判定
  If objEntity.ObjectName = "AcDbBlockReference" Then
    For iii = 1 To 1000
      ii = 1000 - iii + 1
      If Val(Right(objEntity.Name, 3)) = ii Then
        charln = Len(Str(Val(Right(Str(ii), 3)) + 1))
        juki_edaban = Right("000" + Right(Str(ii + 1), charln - 1), 3)
        objEntity.Name = juki_edaban ←（ここで以下のエラーが出ます）
    Exit For
  End If
Next

End If

Next
```

（エラー内容）
実行時エラー　'-2145386476 (80200014X)'
キーが見つかりません

なにか方法があればご教授いただけないでしょうか？
よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

selectionSetのSELECTメソッドにフィルターという機能があり、ブロックのみの図形をselectionSetに格納することができます。
これをfor文で回せば速く検索できます。